# Symfony Configuration: how to differentiate validation based on the value set in the same node level

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I'm writing [a bundle to manage feature prices and plans](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-features) and I have a complex configuration to validate.

**Practically I distinguish between `CountableFeature`s and `RechargeableFeature`s.**

This is a sample of a configuration for the two:

```
features:
    the_name_of_features_set:
        features:
            a_rechargeable_feature:
                type: rechargeable
                # The free amount to recharge the first time (or when you like)
                free_recharge: 10
                cumulable: true
                unitary_price:
                    EUR: 100
                packs:
                    10:
                        EUR: 1000
                    50:
                        EUR: 5000
                    100:
                        EUR: 10000
                    500:
                        EUR: 50000
                    1000:
                        EUR: 100000
            a_countable_feature:
                type: countable
                cumulable: true
                unitary_price:
                    EUR:
                        monthly: 1000
                        yearly: 10000
                packs:
                    10: ~ # <- This is free!
                    50:
                        EUR:
                            monthly: 500
                            yearly: 5000
                    100:
                        EUR:
                            monthly: 1000
                            yearly: 10000
                    500:
                        EUR:
                            monthly: 5000
                            yearly: 50000
                    1000:
                        EUR:
                            monthly: 50000
                            yearly: 500000
```

As you can see the two kinds of features are very similar.
**The only difference is the price structure**: **the `CountableFeature`s can be subscribed** and so the price has to take into account the subscription period (monthly or yearly) **while the `RechargeableFeature`s** are recharged when requested by the user and so they **have only an *unatantum* price** paid when the feature recharge is bought.

But the configuration for the two is very similar and has the same values (`cumulable`, `unitary_price`, `packs`).

**So, when validating the configuration of prices, I have to take into account that if the validating path is `...a_COUNTABLE_FEATURE.UNITARY_PRICE` the price structure has to be expected as composed by a yearly and a monthly interval, while if the validating path is `...a_RECHARGEABLE_FEATURE.UNITARY_PRICE` the price is simple and doesn't have subscription periods.**

**The type of feature is defined in the `type` node**, under `...a_RECHARGEABLE_FEATURE.type`, on the same level as `unitary price`.

**How can I read the value of `type` when I'm validating in `unitary_price` so I can do a different validation for a different kind of feature?** Or, how can I structure the validation `TreeBuilder` to take this into account?

1. **I can create two separate methods: `validateUntantumPrice()` and `validateSubscribtionPrice()` but how can invoke the one or the other based on the value of `type`?**
2. **Or how can I make them aware of the value of `type` so I can do the validation depending on its value checking it directly in the methods?**
3. **I may also set the `type` value in a property in the `Configuration` class itself, but how can I set it during validation, when validating `type`?**

The same applies to configuration values for `packs`: if is a pack of a rechargeable feature, the price is simple (*unatantum*) while if is a pack of a countable feature, the price has subscription periods.

This is the configuration that I came up with. This worked until I introduced the new `CountableFeature` type and now I'm not able to go forward.

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('features');

        $rootNode
            ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
            ->prototype('array')
                ->children()
                    ->arrayNode('features')
                    ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
                        ->prototype('array')
                            ->children()
                                ->enumNode('type')->values(['boolean', 'countable', 'rechargeable'])->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                                // @todo Only if type === Boolean
                                ->scalarNode('enabled')->defaultFalse()->end()
                                // @todo Only if type === Rechargeable
                                ->scalarNode('cumulable')->defaultFalse()->end()
                                // @todo Only if type === Rechargeable
                                ->scalarNode('free_recharge')->defaultNull()->end()
                                // @todo Only if type === Rechargeable
                                ->arrayNode('unitary_price')
                                    // @todo Validate currency code
                                    ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
                                    ->prototype('integer')->end()
                                ->end()
                                // @todo Only if type === Rechargeable
                                ->arrayNode('packs')
                                    ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
                                    ->prototype('array')
                                        // @todo Validate currency code
                                        ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
                                        ->prototype('integer')->end()
                                    ->end()
                                ->end()
                                ->arrayNode('prices')
                                    // @todo Validate currency code
                                    ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
                                    ->prototype('array')
                                        ->children()
                                            // @todo Set this as section
                                            ->scalarNode('monthly')->defaultNull()->end()
                                            ->scalarNode('yearly')->defaultNull()->end()
                                        ->end()
                                    ->end()
                                ->end()
                            ->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end() // End features
                ->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check [conditional validation docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#validation-rules)

Comment: Yes, I did, but I don't know how to go one level up and then continue validation, because... Try to write the validation: you'll understand what I'm saying... I have to first arrive to the node `... a_rechargeable_feature.type`, then, based on its value, validate the following nodes on the same level `... a_rechargeable_feature.unitary_price` and `... a_rechargeable_feature.packs`. But once I've arrived at `... a_rechargeable_feature.type` how can I go up one level and continue the validation?

Comment: I should create two separate methods: `validateUntantumPrice()` and `validateSubscribtionPrice()` but how can invoke the one or the other based on the value of `type`?

Comment: You need to fork it at the `type` level. Either one method with a parameter, or different methods, appended depending on the type.

Comment: Can you write an example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get rid of `packs` to make it a bit more readable, as it is quite wordy.

For configuration yaml

```
features:
    the_name_of_features_set:
        features:
            a_rechargeable_feature:
                type: rechargeable
                free_recharge: 10
                cumulable: true
                unitary_price:
                    EUR: 100
            a_countable_feature:
                type: countable
                cumulable: true
                unitary_price:
                    EUR:
                        monthly: 1000
                        yearly: 10000
```

The conditional configuration definition can be something like this:

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('features');

        $rootNode
            ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
            ->prototype('array')
                ->children()
                    ->arrayNode('features')
                    ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
                        ->prototype('array')
                            ->children()
                                ->enumNode('type')
                                    ->values(['boolean', 'countable', 'rechargeable'])
                                    ->isRequired()
                                    ->cannotBeEmpty()
                                ->end()
                                ->scalarNode('cumulable')->defaultFalse()->end()
                                ->scalarNode('free_recharge')->defaultNull()->end()
                                ->arrayNode('unitary_price')
                                    ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
                                    ->prototype('array')
                                        // here we convert 'EUR'=>100 to 'EUR'=>['_'=>100] to make it an array as declared
                                        ->beforeNormalization()
                                            ->ifTrue(function($v) {return is_numeric($v);})
                                            ->then(function ($v) {
                                                return array('_' => $v);
                                            })
                                            ->end()
                                        ->children()
                                            /// here we define acceptable keys for all types, including the artificial one '_' for scalars
                                            ->scalarNode('monthly')->defaultNull()->end()
                                            ->scalarNode('yearly')->defaultNull()->end()
                                            ->scalarNode('_')->defaultNull()->end()
                                        ->end()
                                    ->end()
                                ->end()
                            ->end()
                            // add validation rules
                            ->validate()
                                ->ifTrue(function($feature) {
                                    return $this->validateFeature($feature);
                                })
                                // tidy up and convert rechargeable price back to scalar
                                ->then(function($feature) {
                                    return $this->processFeature($feature);
                                })
                            ->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end() // End features
                ->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }

    // this part should be self-explanatory

    // validate feature depending on type
    protected function validateFeature($feature)
    {
        switch ($feature['type']) {
            case 'rechargeable':
                $ok = $this->validateRechargeable($feature['unitary_price']);
                break;
            case 'countable':
                $ok = $this->validateCountable($feature['unitary_price']);
                break;
            default:
                // it shouldn't be reachable because of enum type, but you need to handle boolean as well
                $ok = false;
        }
        if(!$ok) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid configuration for ' . json_encode($feature));
        }
        return true;
    }


    // all rechargeables should have scalar '_' type
    protected function validateRechargeable($unitaryPrice)
    {
        return array_reduce(
            $unitaryPrice,
            function($result, $price) {
                return $result && is_numeric($price['_']);
            },
            true
        );
    }

    // all countables should not have '_' scalar type
    protected function validateCountable($unitaryPrice)
    {
        return array_reduce(
            $unitaryPrice,
            function($result, $price) {
                return $result && $price['_'] === null;
            },
            true
        );
    }

    // revert changes depending on type
    protected function processFeature($feature)
    {
        switch ($feature['type']) {
            case 'rechargeable':
                return $this->processRechargeable($feature['unitary_price']);
            case 'countable':
                return $this->processCountable($feature['unitary_price']);
            default:
                // again, not sure what boolean type should do
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unsupported feature type ' . $feature['type']);
        }
    }

    // convert rechargeable arrays back to scalar
    protected function processRechargeable($unitaryPrice)
    {
        array_walk(
            $unitaryPrice,
            function(&$price){
                $price = $price['_'];
            });
        return $unitaryPrice;
    }

    // remove injected '_' from countable arrays
    protected function processCountable($unitaryPrice)
    {
        array_walk(
            $unitaryPrice,
            function(&$price){
                unset($price['_']);
            });
        return $unitaryPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your very good advice, this is the new `Configuration.php`: https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-features/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php Thank you again! :)